# How do I make Excel read my not completely filled in dates correctly in my regional format? (dd.mm)

Tags: excel, date-formatting

I have used a previous version of Excel and OpenOffice Calc, and I was able to format dates to the Ukrainian format "dd.mm.yy" so that when I typed for example "1.8" in the cell marked with this format, it correctly read it as "01.08.22" (the first of August of the current year). Now I'm using the newest Excel and for some reason when I type in "26.08", it autocompletes as "26.01.00" with the following in the formula section: "1/26/1900  12:14:24 AM". Now I could understand not filling in the year I want it to, but not even the month?

And when I do fill it in fully, I don't think it recognizes the text as a date at all! The dates filled in previously in the same document are interpreted and formatted correctly, but not the new ones. The format is identical, I formatted the whole range of cells together.

[image: selected cell: "17.08.22", formula: "8/17/22"]
[image: selected cell: "22.08.22", formula: "22.08.22"]

Typing "8/26" gives me the desired date, but it's not my regional format and it's inconvenient to use.

Is there a way to make Excel do what I want, here?

Comment: Have you tried entering 26/8 as excel may be recognizing the "." as the decimal - based on your system settings.

Comment: Excel parses date input in accord with your Windows Regional short date and time Settings. The cell format in Excel only has to do with how the date is displayed.  You will need to either 1. Change your windows regional settings to Ukrainian; 2. Change how you input your dates to be in accord with your WRS. 3. Write VBA code to translate what you write into an acceptable date.

Comment: Thank you! My region was set to Ukraine and my regional format was set to "recoomended", whatever that means - apparently not matching the region! I've changed it and now it works.